# Expose service in OpenShift Origin Server - router is not working

Tags: openshift-origin

Our team decided to try using OpenShift Origin server to deploy services.
We have a separate VM with OpenShift Origin server installed and working fine. I was able to deploy our local docker images and those services are running fine as well - Pods are up and running, get their own IP and I can reach services endpoints from VM.

The issue is I can't get it working, so the services are exposed outside the machine. I read about the routers, which suppose to be the right way of exposing services, but it just won't work, now some details.

Lets say my VM is 10.48.1.1. The Pod with docker container with one of my services is running on IP 172.30.67.15:

```
~$ oc get svc
NAME                CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
my-svc              172.30.67.15     <none>        8182/TCP   4h
```

The service is simple Spring Boot app with REST endpoint exposed at port 8182.
Whe I call it from VM hosting it, it works just fine:

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://172.30.67.15:8182/home
{"valid":true}
```

Now I wanted to expose it outside, so I created a router:
oc adm router my-svc --ports='8182'

I followed the steps from [OpenShift dev doc](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.2/dev_guide/routes.html) both from CLI and Console UI. The router gets created fine, but then when I want to check its status, I get this:

```
$ oc status
In project sample on server https://10.48.3.161:8443
...
Errors:
  * route/my-svc is routing traffic to svc/my-svc, but either the administrator has not installed a router or the router is not selecting this route.
```

I couldn't find anything about this error that could help me solve the issue - does anyone had similar issue? Is there any other (better/proper?) way of exposing service endpoint? I am new to OpenShift so any suggestions would be appirciated.

Answer (score 6):

If anyone interested, I finally found the "solution".
The issue was that there was no "router" service created - I didn't know it has to be created.

Step by step, in order to create this service I followed the instructions from [OpenShift doc page](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/install_config/install/deploy_router.html#creating-the-router-service-account) which were pretty easy, but I couldn't login using admin account.
I used default admin account

```
$ oc login -u system:admin
```

But instead using available certificate, it kept asking me for password, but it shouldn't. What was wrong? My env variables were reset, and I had to set them again

```
$ export KUBECONFIG="$(pwd)"/openshift.local.config/master/admin.kubeconfig
$ export CURL_CA_BUNDLE="$(pwd)"/openshift.local.config/master/ca.crt
$ sudo chmod +r "$(pwd)"/openshift.local.config/master/admin.kubeconfig
```

This was one of the first steps described in OpenShift docs [OpenShift docs](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/getting_started/administrators.html#downloading-the-binary). After that the certificate is set correctly and login works as expected. As an admin I created router service (1st link) and the route started working - no more errors.
So in the end it came out to be pretty simple and dummy, but given that I didn't have experience with OpenShift it was hard for me to find out what is going on. Hope it will help if someone will have the same issue.